# If two event horizons approach each other, what is going to happen to one in the center?

Tags: black-holes, event-horizon

This is follow up question for
[If two event horizons approach each other, can I observe the collision?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/458521/if-two-event-horizons-approach-each-other-can-i-observe-the-collision). According to the answer by Chiral Anomaly, we can see the merging event horizon, such that.

[image]

What if I locate a single atom at the **exact center** location, what is going to happen?

Comment: Have you considered the Uncertainty Principle while defining the position of the atom?